# Emulate 3DES EDE using only DES

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric, des, 3des

My device doesn't support full 3DES (EDE). How can I emulate one using standard DES? Encryption mode is CBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start by picking three independent DES keys which are not related to each other in any way.

You will want to put DES into ECB mode, **not CBC mode**. You also need to ensure that each encryption and decryption operation is done only on 64-bit blocks and nothing more or less. Padding schemes and the likes will cause a vulnerability in the implementation and will lead to the discovery of the block content via brute force faster than a brute force against each key.

Using the first key, encrypt your plaintext. Using the second key, decrypt that value. Using the third key, encrypt the value for your full block. It looks like this:

`Encrypt(k3, Decrypt(k2, Encrypt(k1, plaintext)))`

Decryption is the other way around and looks like this:

`Decrypt(k1, Encrypt(k2, Decrypt(k3, ciphertext)))`

When you encrypt your blocks with 3DES you then need to apply your mode of operation like CBC or CTR and apply padding if needed.

Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

## Block mode encryption

What you do is that you split the key of size 128 bit (16 byte) or 168 bit (24 byte) in two or three pieces respectively. So for a 16 byte key K you would have two keys Ka and Kb, and for a 24 byte key you would have Ka, Kb and Kc. DES ABC keys have an *effective* strength of about 112 bits, DES ABA keys have an *effective* strength of about 80 bits.

To encrypt a single block of 8 bytes (the block size of both DES and 3DES) you would perform the following cryptographic operation: Cn = E(Ka, D(Kb, E(Kc, Mn))) where Mn is the n'th block of the plain text message and Cn the n'th block of the cipher text. If you don't have a Kc then you may use Ka (DES ABC key vs DES ABA key).

For this you need a single block DES encrypt, which is identical to a single block encrypt in ECB mode, or a single block encrypt with CBC and an IV consisting of 8 bytes valued 00h.

## CBC

So that's the block encryption sorted, now you need some kind of encryption mode and padding mode. I'll explain CBC mode encryption here, ECB should not be used for encryption non-random data.

With CBC mode encryption you XOR a vector to the plain text. The vector is normally just the output of the last DESede encrypted block. As you don't have any preceding cipher text, you need to create the first vector yourself using random data. This vector is called the initialization vector or IV. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block%20chaining%20%28CBC%29) for a clear picture.

## Padding

Block cipher modes only allow full blocks of plain text to be encrypted. So you would need some kind of padding scheme. Although there are many padding modes, PKCS#5 padding is used most of the time. You should pad the plain text like this: pad with bytes valued 0Xh, where X is the number of padding bytes required to create a full block. X should be between 1 and 8: in other words, PKCS#5 padding is always used; this makes it possible to distinquish the padding bytes from the plain text.

If you use padding in an online protocol then you need to protect against padding oracle attacks. In this case it is highly recommended to use some form of integrity checks, e.g. by adding a HMAC over the cipher text using a separate key.

Answer (score 0):

[3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is just DES used three times on the plaintext:

```
ciphertext = E_K3(D_K2(E_K1(plaintext)))
plaintext = D_K1(E_K2(D_K3(ciphertext)))

E_Kn = Encryption with Key number n.
D_Kn = Decryption with Key number n.
```

So you can easily "emulate" 3DES with just DES.

In CBC mode you'll need an IV to start with and then XOR the next plaintext block with the previous ciphertext block. If your device doesn't support CBC then this too is easily "emulated".

Comment: If operations are not performed on block boundaries, it will lead to an insecure implementation due to padding and the application of CBC. CBC and padding must be done after the composite 3DES operation.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray that's not a very clear recommendation Michael. For encryption, I don't think you want to do padding after the composite 3DES operation.

Comment: @owlstead My mistake. You are correct. CBC would be applied afterward for obvious reasons and padding would be done for unaligned blocks in the form of Encrypt(k3, Decrypt(k2, Encrypt(k1, Pad(plaintext)))). It was late when I posted that last night ;)